# CustomCell crash in UItableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have been using a `customCell.xib` with its own `customCellClass` within a `UITableView`,which is built without using `autoLayout` feature(since I need to make it work even on platforms prior to `iOS6`).
The `UITableView` fetches this custom made xib cell in its `dataSource` method.
The dilemma I'm facing is that the `UITableView` crashes abruptly 50 % of times I run it but executes and shows the tabeview perfectly rest of the times..

I m currently using XCode 4.5.

Here's the crash Log i receive ..

> 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews.
>   UITableViewCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call
>   super.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been covered in some detail here, and it is not as simple as simply calling [super layoutSubviews];

["Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews" with UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel)

Try disabling 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' on each of your views. Auto Layout is somehow being triggered, and that causes this bug on UITableView to pop up.

Comment: :Thanx a ton..!! worked perfectly.seems like its a bug in the autolayout feature.

Answer (score -4):

Your custom cell class implementation overrides layoutSubviews without calling super. That's right there in the crash log!