# How can I solve the AssertionFail when AutoLayout is turned on?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I am getting:

```
Assertion failure in -[Cell layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIView.m:5776
2013-01-06 14:58:42.951 Likely[4588:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. Cell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

I wrote:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

in Cell.m file. But doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: possibly same symptoms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding after the call to super.

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

which would result to:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews]; 
    [self layoutIfNeeded]; 
}
```