# Wrong cell height when using auto layout on iOS 7 / iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, autoresizingmask

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750158/autoresizing-issue-of-uicollectionviewcell-contentviews-frame-in-storyboard-pro) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132908/auto-layout-constraints-issue-on-ios7-in-uitableviewcell) SO question. Now the content view has no height problem anymore because I added an auto resizing mask (flexible height/width) to the content view in `updateConstraints` of my custom table view cell for iOS 7.

But the height of the cell still has the same problem. It gets a height of 44 points from the auto resizing mask.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints  
// ...
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a4f61f0 h=-&- v=--&
V:[TestCellAuto_CustomCell:0x7a43bb10(44)]>"
```

The layout is completely destroyed and in the output I get the above error. On iOS 8.1 everything is working fine. Only iOS 7 makes this problems.

How can I tell iOS that it should calculate the correct cell height?

Seems that you have to set `rowHeight` or implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as described in [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/426227).

The height of my cells is always the same, but I don't know why auto layout can't calculate the row height correctly on iOS 7. On iOS 8 the height of the row is wrong after rotation and the layout is messed up. Only if I call `reloadData` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` solves the problem. But for iOS 7 I still have to set the height. Not an ideal solution.

To sum up, this is what I've to do now:

**iOS 7:**

1. `self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;` before adding constraints and
2. define a fixed `rowHeight`

The first is for the `contentView` and the second for the `UITableViewCell`.

**iOS 8:**

- I can either set a fixed `rowHeight` or
- use `reloadData` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

What is wrong with auto layout? Am I doing something wrong? Are you always setting a fixed height?

Comment: iOS 7 did not allow the cell height to be calculated automatically from the constraints. iOS 8 does allow this. If you need to support iOS 7 you will have to perform the calculation from the constraints / implicit sizes yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why does the sizing information gets lost when I rotate the device on iOS 8? It seems that I'm missing something. For iOS 8 I don't need to calculate - it's done automatically as you said (except the rotation problem). How does your calculation does look like? The same like in the linked post *Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights*?

Comment: I have no idea why the sizing information is not working when you rotate on iOS 8. It should just work so I think it must be something in your constraints. For iOS 7 I always went with a fixed row height but basically if you follow that linked post it will work. So I'm not sure what you're missing. I suggest you post a more specific question about the iOS 8 rotation problem with example code & pictures of your constraints.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881764/on-rotation-cell-height-gets-lost-on-ios-8-when-using-auto-layout