# UICollectionView layout issue on iOS7

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uicollectionview

I am developing an app that supports iOS7 and iOS8. On iOS8 running on an iPad 2 the app runs fine. No issues. However on iOS7 there is an issue with one of my `UICollectionView`'s which I just can't seem to fix. I am using `AutoLayout` and out of desperation, have tried `springs and struts` which made no difference.

So this is how the cell looks at 320 width:

[image: 320 Width]

Here are the `AutoLayout constraints` applied to the `UICollectionView`

[image: Autolayout constraints]

And here is what happens when its on an iPad with iOS 7.1

[image: iPad + iOS7]

Whatever I try I always get the same result on iOS7. On iOS8 with an iPad the cell displayed perfectly fine.

Not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I found the answer incase anyone else suffers the same issue.

The accepted answer from this SO question: [Auto layout constraints issue on iOS7 in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132908/auto-layout-constraints-issue-on-ios7-in-uitableviewcell)

Actually helped me.

Here is what i did in my `UICollectionViewCell`'s subclass:

```
    -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self){

        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;


            return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This solved the issue for me.