# Issue with Autolayout constraints in iOS 7 / iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

In my custom UITableViewCell, I have added multiple UILabel and UIImage and added constraints by visual format. All code working fine in iOS 8. but in iOS 7 that is not case, i'm getting auto layout warnings and content is disturbed.

Some code in custom cell :

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

Warnings on iOS 7:

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this:

1. look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
2. find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
   (
       "",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       ""
   )

   Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Comment: Could you include the rest of the error message (describing the constraints in conflict)?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19154287/2954866

Comment: not helped, at the end I had to shift all code to nib and worked