# Adding subview to tableview using autolayout

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I was trying to add a subview to tableview using autolayout, but I get this Assertion failure when I do so.

" *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'"

My code

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[parentView addSubview:view];

[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:0.0 constant:10.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:50.0];

    [parentView addConstraint:c1];
    [parentView addConstraint:c3];
    [parentView addConstraint:c2];
    [parentView addConstraint:c1];
```

but if I set frame to the view without any autolayout constraint, it works fine.
I couldn't figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Did you call `[super layoutSubviews]` from within your `-layoutSubviews` implementation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a "Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews" error every time my app launches now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837097/why-am-i-getting-a-auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews)