# Use auto layout by code, work fine in iOS 7 but crash when iOS 6

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I develop my app in XCode 5, and I create my view controller(`UIViewController` instance) in storyboard. And I add a `UITableView` as its' subview, after that I create a custom tableview cell.

Then, in the view controller's  .m file, I create a `UIActivityIndicatorView` instance and add it to the cell as it subview. The `UIActivityIndicatorView` lazy load method like below:

```
-(UIActivityIndicatorView *)loadingIndicator
{

    if (!_loadingIndicator) {
     _loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    [self addSubview:_loadingIndicator];

    _loadingIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *centerX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_loadingIndicator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.questionBodyWebView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0f];

    NSLayoutConstraint *centerY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_loadingIndicator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.questionBodyWebView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

    [self addConstraints:@[centerX, centerY]];  
    }
    return _loadingIndicator;
}
```

It will work fine in my ipad mini(iOS7), but when I run it in simulator ipad(iOS 6.1), it will crash, and the console output like this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

Can some one tell me why? Wait for your help, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews" with UITableViewCell subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel)

Comment: It seems a good way use swizzling to fix the error, but Apple will allowed this?

Comment: Yep, swizzling is widely used (although, personally, I'm not a big fan of it).