# How do I position a subview in UIPageViewController using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` subclass, and in its `viewDidLoad` I want to add a `UILabel` to its `self.view`. This works fine if I set its position using frames, but if I try to position it using Auto Layout, I get:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_UIPageViewControllerContentView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.58/UIView.m:8742

How am I supposed to position this UILabel to show up in the `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: Assuming that assertion is because of a constraint conflict, did you remember translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO?

Comment: Yes, I did remember to.

Comment: Are you also getting the message "Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews"?

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be happening because `UIPageViewController`'s view (which is actually a `_UIPageViewControllerContentView`) doesn't handle subviews and autolayout as expected (at least in iOS 7; it worked fine for me in iOS 8).

You can get around this by not using autolayout, but I wanted to use autolayout so I ended up redoing my view controllers to avoid adding subviews to `UIPageViewController`.

Instead of subclassing `UIPageViewController`, I created a container view controller (a subclass of `UIViewController`) with a `UIPageViewController` as a child view controller. The custom subviews that I initially had in `UIPageViewController` were then added to the container's `view`. I also made the container the data source and delegate for the `UIPageViewController`.

There's a related thread where people got the same assertion failure but with a `UITableViewCell`: ["Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews" with UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel). Most of the suggestions there don't work or aren't applicable to UIPageViewController, but it helped me figure out why adding subviews with autolayout might cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also subclass UIPageViewController and implement this workaround:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface MyPageViewController : UIPageViewController
@end

@implementation MyPageViewController
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self applyLayoutSubviewsWorkaroundIfNeeded];
}

- (void)applyLayoutSubviewsWorkaroundIfNeeded {
    // UIPageViewController does not support AutoLayout in iOS7, we get the following runtime error
    // "_UIPageViewControllerContentView’s implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super…"
    // This workaround calls the missing layoutSubviews method of UIView.
    if ([self iOSVersionIsLowerThan8]) {
        IMP uiviewLayoutSubviewsImplementation = class_getMethodImplementation([self.view class], @selector(layoutSubviews));
        typedef void (*FunctionFromImplementation)(id, SEL);
        FunctionFromImplementation uiviewLayoutSubviewsFunction = (FunctionFromImplementation)uiviewLayoutSubviewsImplementation;
        uiviewLayoutSubviewsFunction(self.view, @selector(layoutSubviews));
    }
}

- (BOOL)iOSVersionIsLowerThan8 {
    // This is just one way of checking if we are on iOS7. 
    // You can use whatever method suits you best
    return ![self respondsToSelector(popoverPresentationController)];
}
@end
```