# Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:]

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5, uisearchbar, ios7.1

I want to use an `UISearchDisplayController` on `UIViewController`, that includes an `UITableView`.
I use Autolayout. When i try to put the SearchBar (_searchBar) in the tableHeaderView with

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;
```

I get the error
'`NSInternalInconsistencyException`', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

Disabling Autolayout, the error disappears, but i **need** Autolayout...

The error appears, when I use Custom Cells or StandardCells...

The error appears, when the TableView has no rows...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a general solution to this problem, or at least a way of finding the cause of it:

- Turn on exception breakpoints
- Subclass `UITableView` and override `layoutSublayersOfLayer:`, just calling super
- Run your app - you will stop in your new method
- In the debugger, type `po [self _autolayoutTrace]`

This will show you a printout of every view in the window, with the views where auto layout has not been able to come up with a solution highlighted by asterisks or `AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT`. These are the views you need to investigate the constraints for.

Comment: In Swift projects: `expr -l objc++ -o -- [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]`  (source: https://carpeaqua.com/2015/07/07/auto-layout-debugging-in-swift/)

Answer (score 6):

When adding a subview to UITableView there are some specific requirements for the subview. Consider adding the subview to another view(superview) in your controller instead of UITableView.

["Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews" with UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel)

Comment: As @Vladimir points in his answer, autolayouting a view in a tableView will likely trigger that error (in the table itself, or even autolayouting a tableViewHeader/Footer). Just as a clarifying note, I see that this error might not appear for some layouts in iOS 8, but will certainly appear in iOS 7.