# Auto Layout exception when auto layout is disabled

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an Xcode 5, iOS 7 project. In my Storyboard Auto Layout is disabled. However I still occasionally get the following exception when trying to present a model view controller.

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Auto Layout still
>   required after executing -layoutSubviews. MyScrollView's
>   implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.

My layoutSubviews methods all call super. Therefore that is not the problem.

How come I am getting auto layout errors even although it is disabled in the Storyboard file?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel

Comment: The thing I am trying to emphasise is that I have disabled Auto Layout in the Storyboard for the view controller. How come even although it is disabled, it is still active?