# iOS 7.1 UITableView layoutSubviews issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm working on a project that must support both iOS 8 and iOS 7.1. Right now I'm running into a problem that only appears on iOS 7.1 but works properly on iOS 8. I have a ViewController that contains a tableview and a custom view in the tableHeaderView. I'll post the code as follows. All constraints are added programatically.

//View Controller.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.commentsArray = [NSMutableArray new];

  [self.commentsArray addObject:@"TEST"];
  [self.commentsArray addObject:@"TEST"];
  [self.commentsArray addObject:@"TEST"];
  [self.commentsArray addObject:@"TEST"];
  [self.commentsArray addObject:@"TEST"];
  [self.commentsArray addObject:@"TEST"];

  [self.view addSubview:self.masterTableView];

  self.masterTableView.tableHeaderView = self.detailsView;

  [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];


}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}


//Table view getter
- (UITableView *)masterTableView
{
  if(!_masterTableView)
  {
    _masterTableView = [UITableView new];
    _masterTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    _masterTableView.backgroundColor                = [UIColor greyColor];

    _masterTableView.delegate                       = self;
    _masterTableView.dataSource                     = self;

    _masterTableView.separatorStyle                 = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _masterTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator   = NO;
    _masterTableView.separatorInset                 = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

  }

  return _masterTableView;
}

-(void)updateViewConstraints
{
 NSDictionary *views = @{
      @"table"        : self.masterTableView,
      @"details"      : self.detailsView,
 };


  NSDictionary *metrics = @{
                            @"width"  : @([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width)
                            };
    //Table view constraints
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[table]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[table]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];

  //Details View
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[details(width)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[details]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

}


//Details View Getter
- (DetailsView *)detailsView
{
  if(!_detailsView)
  {

   _detailsView = [[DetailsView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 100)];
    _detailsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

  return _detailsView;
}
```

Now the details view contains some basic subviews which all derive from a UIView and the details view itself derives from a more general super class. I'll post the code as follows.

```
//Parent View 
@interface ParentView (): UIView

- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];

  if (self)
  {
    [self setupViews];
  }

  return self;
}


- (void)setupViews
{
  [self addSubview:self.publishedTimeView];
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
  NSDictionary *views = @{
                          @"time"         : self.publishedTimeView,
                          };


  // Header with published video time
  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[time]-10-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[time(11)]" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];

  [super updateConstraints];
}

//Getter for the timePublished view added to the detail view. Will not post all its related code for //the sake of brevity.
- (TimePublishedDetailView *)publishedTimeView
{
  if(!_publishedTimeView)
  {
    _publishedTimeView = [TimePublishedDetailView new];
    _publishedTimeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  }

  return _publishedTimeView;
}

//Child View (or the detailsView) of the view controller.

@interface DetailsView : ParentView


@implementation RecordingDetailsView

- (void)updateConstraints
{
  NSDictionary *views = @{
                          @"time"         : self.publishedTimeView,
                          };

   //Vertical alignment of all views

  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[time]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

  [super updateConstraints];

}


- (void)setModel:(DetailViewModel *)model
{
  self.publishedTimeView.date = model.dateTime;

  [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  [self layoutSubviews];
}
```

Now on iOS 8 this looks like this: 
[image]

However on iOS 7.1 this will crash with this error message:

"Exception: Auto layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super"

I've googled this and played around with the code in my layout calls to see if I can remedy the problem but so far have been unsuccessful. If anyone could post some tips or advice on how to fix this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Any reason I am doing what? Can you be specific?

Comment: Sorry, my edit didn't get updated! Have you tried doing things in different view lifecycle methods? You might get more of an idea on what's going on

Comment: Yeah I've done quite a bit of testing and experimentation with this. Went even as far as commenting out the timePublishedView as well and this still seems to happen only on iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I ran into a similar problem recently and after a lot of Googling, trying and failing I made it work with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941256/1732725) and a few changes.

Just add this category to your project and call `[UITableView fixLayoutSubviewsMethod];` only once (I recommend inside `AppDelegate`).

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

@implementation UITableView (FixUITableViewAutolayoutIHope)

+ (void)fixLayoutSubviewsMethod
{
    Method existing = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(layoutSubviews));
    Method new = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews));

    method_exchangeImplementations(existing, new);
}

- (void)_autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self _autolayout_replacementLayoutSubviews]; // not recursive due to method swizzling
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```