# Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UICollectionView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super

Tags: ios, collectionview, flowlayout, layoutsubviews

I use `UICollectionView` with default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. It works on iOS 8, but on iOS 7.1 I get

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still
>   required after executing -layoutSubviews. UICollectionView's
>   implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super

I found this [“Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews” with UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel?rq=1) but none of the solution works

Another clue is that I add some views into the UICollectionView, and setup AutoLayout for that view

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.collectionView addSubview:button];

    [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.top.right.equalTo(self.collectionView);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(30);
    }];
```

This is what in my custom UICollectionView

```
@implementation FTGCollectionView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //[self layoutIfNeeded]; // Should not call as it cause collection view to not scroll
}

@end
```

Comment: have you override layoutSubviews? if so, have you called super.layoutSubviews? if not then here you are :)

Comment: I see that this can happen to UICollectionView, UITextField, UITableView, UINavigationBar, ... My workaround is to disable autoLayout for subviews (and grand children subviews) and set frame manually

Comment: For UICollectionView, we can add subview into `UICollectionReusableView ` in its `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is an iOS 7 bug, instead of `[self.collectionView addSubview:button];` I change to `[self.view addSubview:button];`, self.view is self.collectionView's parent view.

So in iOS7 don't add subview to UICollectionView and use auto-layout for that subview